# What is "lookup" argument of NestedSimpleRouter class?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I'm using [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) to create several nested API endpoints.

Let's take a look at the next piece of code in my **routes.py** file:

```
from rest_framework_nested.routers import SimpleRouter, NestedSimpleRoute

base_router = SimpleRouter()
base_router.register("categories", CategoryModelView)

dishes_types_router = NestedSimpleRouter(base_router, r"categories", lookup="category")
dishes_types_router.register(r"types_of_dishes", DishesTypeModelView, basename="dishes_type")
```

**My question is**: what does `lookup="category"` in the fourth row do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While going trough the source code of `drf-nested-routers` repository, I've found this explanation in the doc strings in both `NestedSimpleRouter` and `NestedDefaultRouter`:

> **lookup**:
> The regex variable that matches an instance of the parent-resource
> will be called '*<parent-viewset.lookup_field>'
> In the example above, lookup=domain and the parent viewset looks up
> on 'pk' so the parent lookup regex will be 'domain_pk'.
> Default: 'nested*' where  is 1+parent_router.nest_count

[The source code](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers/blob/master/rest_framework_nested/routers.py) and [the example](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers#quickstart) that's talked about in the explanation.